# How to avoid override the back page in Android?

Tags: android

I'm recording multiple audio voice and adding one button for go to back on previous activity after recording . But after multiple recording and try for go back to previous page , the page does not switch to directly previous. If i record 4 audio voice and try to go to previous click on button he will 4 time display the same page and showing 4 record , again click showing 3, again click showing 2 and last 1 and then go to previous. How to solve this issue. Can someone help me.

Here is my Record Activity code

```
  imageRecord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_Record);
        imageRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickCount += 1;
                Log.e("clickCount ", " click !!! " + clickCount);

                if (clickCount == 1)
                {
                    btnSaveRecord.setEnabled(false);
                    btnCancelRecord.setEnabled(false);
                    myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();


                    if (vesselId == null) {

                        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
                        newAudioFile = 0 + "_" + s.format(new Date()) + ".mp3";
                        Log.e(" newAudioFile ", " = " + newAudioFile);
                        outputFile = baseDir + "/classnkk_audio/" + newAudioFile;
                        Log.e("outputFile ", " = " + outputFile);
                        myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

                        imageRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.record);
                        try {
                            myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                            myAudioRecorder.start();
                            myChronometer.start();

                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else if (vesselId != null) {
                        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
                        newAudioFile = vesselId + "_" + s.format(new Date()) + ".mp3";
                        Log.e(" newAudioFile ", " = " + newAudioFile);
                        outputFile = baseDir + "/classnkk_audio/" + newAudioFile;
                        Log.e("outputFile ", " = " + outputFile);
                        myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
                        imageRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.record);
                        try {
                            myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                            myAudioRecorder.start();
                            myChronometer.start();

                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                } else if (clickCount == 2)
                {
                    btnSaveRecord.setEnabled(true);
                    btnCancelRecord.setEnabled(true);
                    imageRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.record_pause);
                    myAudioRecorder.stop();
                    myAudioRecorder.reset();
                    myAudioRecorder.release();
                    myAudioRecorder = null;
                    myChronometer.stop();
                    long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - myChronometer.getBase();
                    Log.e("elapsedMillis ", " of myChronometer !!! " + elapsedMillis);
                }

                if (clickCount == 2) {
                    imageRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.record);
                    clickCount = 0;
                    myAudioRecorder = null;
                    myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    Log.e("(clickCount == 3 ) ", " click !!! " + clickCount);
                }
            }
        });

btnCancelRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCancelRecord);
        btnCancelRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(ItemDetail_Record.this, 
                 AllPost_ItemDetails.class);
                //i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                }
        });


        btnSaveRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveRecord);
        btnSaveRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
               Intent i = new Intent(ItemDetail_Record.this,            
                AllPost_ItemDetails.class);
                //i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
               uploadrecord(strUploadActivityObjectId);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is My Another activity

```
imgView_BackToAllPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(AllPost_ItemDetails.this , CustomActionActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

    imgButn_AudioRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(AllPost_ItemDetails.this, ItemDetail_Record.class);
                    i.putExtra("DetailView_ActivityId", strActivityId);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 1234);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Post your entire activity.  We need to see what you are doing with each recording.

Comment: I don't want to add this onBackPressed()  function right now . Can we solve without this?

Comment: No, because I can't see how your activities are being navigated.